# Test hypothesis of rare event with real life data using a Bayesian Model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

Since I found out what Bayesian Theory I got really interested in using it in my everyday life to find a numerous of things, but I wasn't able to get any result due to my lack of understanding of research using statistics and how to develop a model which is 'accurate'.

On of the problems I'm trying to solve is if either I have or don't have some allergies.

I know that in order to start the Bayesian model I have to have a **prior probability** , in this case I'm using the data I found on the internet of how many people have that allergy (**10%** of all people do), then I have to do some sort of update on that probability stating whether I have or have not suffered a symptom, this is where the test gets trick, I don't know how to perform such tests and get conclusive data out of it.

I'm testing for an lactose intolerance, I drink milk everyday and always had, but I'm not sure whether I have developed an intolerance in the last year or whether I have other allergy.

What I tried to do is stay some days without drinking milk, and check if I had any major allergy attack, I have those a few times a year (under 10x), this test is flawed from the start since it's a very **rare event**. I could try to drink a lot of milk and see if this causes one of the attacks, but I rather not.

So, what's a good approach to get good data out of events like this (rare attacks, and low prior probability)?

I want to test other allergies too, should I do each hypothesis test apart from each other, or is there a way to perform multiple hypothesis test in the same time?

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but just wanted to mention that intolerances aren't allergies; for lactose intolerance your body is missing the lactase enzyme. Still a good question and you don't need to edit, just thought I would let you know. Hope you get some good answers.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know, I always find people referring to it as milk allergy and lactose intolerance in the same way. Nice to know :)